# How to install xsock?

Tags: c, sockets, asyncsocket, xsocket

I downloaded library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsock/.
In INSTALL file are steps to run this libs.
I changed location to xsock/libxsock and type in terminal ./configure
Nothing happend... How to solve this?

1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
   ./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type`
   sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute`
   configure' itself.

   Running `configure' takes a while.  While running, it prints some
    messages telling which features it is checking for.
2. Type `make' to compile the package.
3. ...
   4...

Comment: Did it output any messages when you ran `./configure` ?  What shell are you using?

Comment: " No such file or directory". I installed autoconf...

Answer (score 0):

The library is broken, and cannot be built as distributed. A number of autoconf/automake files are missing from the archive.

Given that the library appears to have been primarily developed on Windows systems, it seems likely to me that the UNIX parts of the build process for this library have not been maintained, or may never have worked at all. My recommendation is that you find another library — this one seems to be largely unmaintained, and the code quality seems rather low.

Comment: What is recomendet socket library for C?

Comment: For C, the POSIX socket API is universal, and requires no external libraries on most systems. Without any more specific requirements, it's what I'd recommend that you use.